# CKEditor not loading: Sometimes executes code before the needed JS file is loaded

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, asset-pipeline

I have two working view pages (edit and new) that include a text area to which I'm trying to add CKEditor. The view page includes:

```
<%= f.text_area :page %>                 // This produces a textarea with id image_page

<script>
  CKEDITOR.replace( 'image_page' );      // I also tried wrapping this in `$(id='image_page').ready(function () {` `CKEDITOR.replace( 'image_page' );` `});` but that made no difference.
</script>
```

To the header of `application.html.erb` I added `ckeditor.js`:

```
<% if controller_name == 'images' && ['new', 'edit'].include?(action_name) %>
  <script src="/assets/ckeditor.js"></script>
<% end %>
```

The custom base path (all files are in `public/assets/ckeditor453/`) is added to `application.js`. I did not require ckeditor.js here since that's already included in the above header:

```
var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/assets/ckeditor453/';
```

**Problem:** When visiting the new or edit view via a link in another view (very standard links: e.g. `edit_image_path(image)`), then the new or edit page loads without the ckeditor and there's a JS error saying `ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined`. Upon refreshing the same page, it loads correctly with ckeditor present (and the error is thus gone). 
 When visiting the new or edit path directly (thus not via a link but entering their address in the browser's location bar), the page immediately loads correctly with the need for reloading it.

Is there perhaps a JS loading/order problem for `ckeditor.js`, so that when the page is trying to call `CKEDITOR.replace`, the `ckeditor.js` isn't loaded yet (at least not when visiting the page via a link)?

Does anyone understand this behavior and can shed insight in what I can do to solve it?

**Update:**

- Moving the script that loads `ckeditor.js` to the top of the header in `application.html.erb` doesn't make a difference.
- When I completely disable turbolinks for the app, the problem is gone. But this is not a solution since I need turbolinks for the app.
- Adding the gem jquery-turbolinks didn't solve it.
- I question whether `var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/assets/ckeditor453/';` is placed in the right file...? In fact, I suddenly had a problem with a js file on another view, which has always worked, and these problems were gone when I remove `var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/assets/ckeditor453/';` from `application.js` (the problems described in this post remained). But where then should I include `var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/assets/ckeditor453/';`?
- Should I perhaps include `//= require ckeditor` in `application.js` and not include it in the header of `application.html.erb`? But if I include `var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/assets/ckeditor453/';` `//= require ckeditor` in `application.js` it can't find the file. Also tried `//= require ckeditor453/ckeditor` but still couldn't find the file.

Really stuck, don't know what to do...

Comment: Try to navigate http://localhost:3000/ckeditor.js. Is anything displayed in your browser?

Comment: Yes, and the page works fine most of the time, just not always, so the link to the js file can't be the problem.

Comment: have you tried to change `$(id='image_page')` to `$('#image_page')`

Comment: Tried it, but that makes no difference. Also, it seems more of an issue of that `ckeditor.js` needs to have been loaded before the second script gets executed, and that's not something controlled by the `$(id=...` line.

Comment: you probably have issues with turbolinks

Comment: Have you tried ckeditor-rails? https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails

Comment: I don't really want to use a gem for this.

Comment: try to disable turbolinks temporarily. Or move `ckeditor.js` into header.

Comment: I added what happens if I place `ckeditor.js` to the original post. It then still didn't work. If I remove turbolinks it indeed works. But what to do, since turbolinks is of course necessary for the app... Should I perhaps require `ckeditor.js` in `application.js`?(I couldn't get this to work, perhaps because `ckeditor.js` is in the public folder and therefore not possible to require in `application.js`...?

Comment: try to add jquery-turbolinks https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks

Comment: Added and installed it, but the behavior/problem remained the same. I'm also wonderingen if `var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/assets/ckeditor453/';` is in the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post on Github (https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails/issues/28) describes the same behavior and confirms turbolinks is the problem. To the links that link to pages that use ckeditor, I disabled turbolinks. This solved it:

```
link_to "Go", edit_image_path(image), data: {no_turbolink: true }
```